# What does described mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "described" mean in the sentence?

> "Two contenders are from the genus Patu: males of Patu digua **described** in Colombia had a body length of 0.37 millimeters (0.014 inches)"

this was taken from https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/smallest-spider

I couldn't find anything about this on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/describe

Comment: When you get a phrase with a participle following a noun, you can often insert "which is/was/are/wer" before the participle to get the same meanings. So _which were described in Colombia_.

Answer (score 2):

It means precisely what your dictionary link says - 'to say or write what someone or something is like'. You perhaps don't recognise the way the verb has been used in the sentence structure of your example as it isn't a simple *subject, verb, object* sentence like "*John described Mary* as having long hair".

In your example, "*described in Columbia*" is modifying the subject noun 'males of Patu digua'. So, the sentence means that two specimens found in Columbia were described (presumably by those who found them) as having a body length of 0.37 mm.

Comment: but It's described in

Comment: @coolguy yes, the specimens from columbia were described as having a body length of 0.37mm. "Specimens described" is like "cakes eaten", or "money spent".